# Helm _helpers.tpl: Calling defined templates in other template definitions

Tags: templates, go, kubernetes, go-templates, kubernetes-helm

## Helm _helpers.tpl?

Helm allows for the use of [Go templating](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) in resource files for Kubernetes.

A file named `_helpers.tpl` is usually used to define Go template helpers with this syntax:

```
{{- define "yourFnName" -}}
{{- printf "%s-%s" .Values.name .Values.version | trunc 63 -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Which you can then use in your `*.yaml` resource files like so:

```
{{ template "yourFnName" . }}
```

## The Question

How can I use the helpers I define, in other helper definitions?

For example, what if I have a helper for the application name, and want to use that in the definition for a helper which determines the ingress host name?

I have tried calling helpers in other definitions a couple different ways. Given this basic helper function:

```
{{- define "host" -}}
{{- printf "%.example.com" <Somehow get result of "name" helper here> -}}
{{- end -}}
```

I have tried the following:

```
{{- printf "%.example.com" {{ template "name" . }} -}}
{{- printf "%.example.com" {{- template "name" . -}} -}}
{{- printf "%.example.com" ( template "name" . ) -}}
{{- printf "%.example.com" template "name" . -}}
# Separator
{{- $name := {{ template "environment" . }} -}}
{{- printf "%.example.com" $name -}}
# Separator
{{- $name := template "environment" . -}}
{{- printf "%.example.com" $name -}}
# Separator
{{- $name := environment -}}
{{- printf "%.example.com" $name -}}
```

Is it possible to even do this? If so, how?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should use [Nested template definitions](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Nested_template_definitions).

In your particular case it is:

```
{{- define "host" -}}
{{ template "name" . }}.example.com
{{- end -}}
```

Answer (score 24):

You can use `(include ... )` syntax. Example of including previously defined template `foo`:

```
{{- define "bar" -}}
{{- printf "%s-%s" (include "foo" .) .Release.Namespace | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Comment: pls also see the difference of using `template` and `include`:  https://github.com/technosophos/k8s-helm/blob/master/docs/charts_tips_and_tricks.md#know-your-template-functions