# Kubernetes Helm chart: Use _helpers.tpl to concat values and feed back into Values.yaml

Tags: go, yaml, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I am new to Kubernetes, Helm, and Golang. Basically, I'm trying to concat strings in my values.yaml file to populate another value in my values.yaml file. I'm using _helpers.tpl to do this (in an attempt to understand Helm and Golang better).  I could just write "users: "datafeed:password:::incoming" " in my values.yaml file and be done with it; but would like to avoid that.

I have the following in my values.yaml file:

```
sftp:
  users: ""
  username: "datafeed"
  password: "password"
  incoming: "incoming"
```

And want the **final** values.yaml file to read:

```
sftp:
  users: "datafeed:password:::incoming"
  username: "datafeed"
  password: "password"
  incoming: "incoming"
```

To do this, I am trying to edit the _helpers.tpl file. I have tried

```
{{- define "sftp.users" -}}
{{- .Values.sftp.users: .Values.sftp.username+":"+.Values.sftp.password+":::"+.Values.sftp.incoming -}}
{{- end -}}
```

and

```
{{- define "sftp.users" -}}
{{- .Values.sftp.users:= .Values.sftp.username+":"+.Values.sftp.password+":::"+.Values.sftp.incoming -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Then I tried making each segment a variable (and deleted the explicit values in the values.yaml file):

```
{{- define "sftp.users" -}}
{{ $username:= "datafeed" }}
{{ $password:= "password" }}
{{ $incoming:= "incoming" }}
{{- .Values.sftp.users= {{$username}}+":"+{{$password}}":::"+{{$incoming}} -}}
```

and then setting the fields/keys explicitly:

```
username: {{ .Values.sftp.username | default "datafeed" }}
password: {{ .Values.sftp.password | default "password" }}
incoming: {{ .Values.sftp.incoming | default "incoming" }}
{{- .Values.sftp.users:= username+":"+password+":::"+incoming -}}
```

and:

```
{{define "username"}}datafeed{{end}}
{{define "password"}}password{{end}}
{{define "incoming"}}incoming{{end}}
{{define "users"}}{{template "username"}}:{{template "password"}}:::{{template "incoming"}}{{end}}
{{- printf "users" -}}
{{- .Values.sftp.users: users -}}
```

I have also looked at previous posts:
[Helm _helpers.tpl: Calling defined templates in other template definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46719082/helm-helpers-tpl-calling-defined-templates-in-other-template-definitions?rq=1)
[Kubernetes Helm, combine two variables with a string in the middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45278655/kubernetes-helm-combine-two-variables-with-a-string-in-the-middle?newreg=1f09fb8852fa44f2871d96bec723d61c)
[How to get values from values.yaml to _helpers.tpl in helm charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56679428/how-to-get-values-from-values-yaml-to-helpers-tpl-in-helm-charts)

None of this seems to work. I can't tell if it's my approach or my syntax. Probably both.

Comment: If you're still intresseted, I think this question provides an answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65358727/how-to-concatenate-a-variable-and-a-string-with-the-go-templates